# Provide read only access to an S3 path in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I see that in many questions / discussions, (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281310/read-only-access-to-s3-folder-on-amazon) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61669048/aws-s3-bucket-policy-read-only-access-for-specific-folder) one) when needed to grant **read** only access to a bucket (or even only a specific path/subdir of a bucket), the following bucket-level permission needs to be given as well

```
{
        "Sid": "MyStatement",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
},
```

Why is this permission necessary even when then only requirement is to be able to just **read** one of buckets subdirs, e.g. `/path/to/somewhere` ?

Comment: For individual objects it shouldn't be necessary, but prefixes are different - to get information about the objects with a given prefix you need to be able to list the items in a bucket to find out about the items with a prefix.

Comment: It's going to depend on what your S3 client is actually doing. If it simply attempts to 'get' an object then you don't need s3:ListBucket.

Comment: @jarmod in which case am I going to also need the bucket-level `ListBucket` permission? I assume when accessing it via the UI console?

Comment: The difference between having ListBucket perms vs not having it is just behavior when an object doesn't exist. If you call getObject and it doesn't exist and you don't have ListBucket perms, a 403 will return instead of a 404, which can be confusing.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here? Is it to give download access for a specific S3 prefix to a specific IAM user within the S3 console? The S3 console obviously uses a number of list-style APIs to build its views.

Comment: [Writing IAM Policies: Grant Access to User-Specific Folders in an Amazon S3 Bucket | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/)